# What's the difference between [narration] and [narrative-techniques], should they be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a [narration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narration) tag and a [narrative-techniques](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative-techniques), as I was about to use one of them for a question in mind, I found their descriptions as:

> [narrative-techniques](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative-techniques)
>   Methods for describing how events unfold in the game world.

> [narration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narration)
>   The act of describing the events that unfold in the game world, either as player or gamemaster.

They are very similar, [if you search questions that contain the two tags](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative-techniques+narration), you get 4 questions tagged with both, out of the 43 questions tagged as either, as of this writing.

So what's the distinction between the two? Should we make them synonyms? Is there any merit to that? Can we just improve the tag wiki instead, to better distinguish the two?

---

Afterthought: [narration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narration) already has [description](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/description) for a synonym.

Comment: If we do decide these two mean different things, I'd be interested in seeing if it's practical to reword one or the other to make their difference more distinct.

Comment: Narration is the KISS principle way of saying "narrative techniques" so I think you are on the right track with this ...

Comment: So it looks like we should merge them. Can someone do it for us? (I don't have a 5 score in the tag)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Merge them

And keep the longer (aka [narrative-techniques](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative-techniques)) as the synonymous one.

Comment: Since no one has taken a stance yet, here's mine. ☺

Answer (score 5):

This merge has been done. Here's some historical info in case we want to reverse this.

Here are the questions which had [narrative-techniques](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative-techniques) but not [narration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narration):

- [Should I immediately tell players when a monster dies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105439/should-i-immediately-tell-players-when-a-monster-dies)
- [Am I allowed to cut away from the player characters to show things happening elsewhere?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103927/am-i-allowed-to-cut-away-from-the-player-characters-to-show-things-happening-els)
- [How do I narrate a failed damage roll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92907/how-do-i-narrate-a-failed-damage-roll)
- [Balance between planning and improvising](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19203/balance-between-planning-and-improvising) [closed]
- [How can I efficiently convey different perceptions of the same thing to different players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96643/how-can-i-efficiently-convey-different-perceptions-of-the-same-thing-to-differen) [duplicate]
- [How can I foreshadow the identity of a villain without making it too obvious?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95257/how-can-i-foreshadow-the-identity-of-a-villain-without-making-it-too-obvious)
- [How do I narrate a player's PC's actions without causing unintended consequences for the PC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92870/how-do-i-narrate-a-players-pcs-actions-without-causing-unintended-consequences)
- [Narrative Explanation of Wand Creation Cost [Pathfinder]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88515/narrative-explanation-of-wand-creation-cost-pathfinder) [closed]
- [How to begin a role-playing scenario in medias res?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67006/how-to-begin-a-role-playing-scenario-in-medias-res)
- [What game made leading questions a GM technique?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55121/what-game-made-leading-questions-a-gm-technique)
- [How do you convey the feeling of a crowded area?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68188/how-do-you-convey-the-feeling-of-a-crowded-area)
- [How much creative and descriptive power should I offer my players? Is it different for sandbox campaigns?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60005/how-much-creative-and-descriptive-power-should-i-offer-my-players-is-it-differe) [closed]
- [Pros and cons of 2nd person narration?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55865/pros-and-cons-of-2nd-person-narration)
- [Mechanics and methods for playing a quantum-superposition of worlds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18932/mechanics-and-methods-for-playing-a-quantum-superposition-of-worlds) [closed]
- [How to convey the tone of Shadowrun](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/17052/how-to-convey-the-tone-of-shadowrun)
- [Fantasy and magic in a primarily realistic setting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15798/fantasy-and-magic-in-a-primarily-realistic-setting)

(I noticed a lot of these are about narration.)

These questions had both [narrative-techniques](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative-techniques) and [narration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narration):

- [What type of speech do I use when GMing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72778/what-type-of-speech-do-i-use-when-gming)
- [How can I deal with PC access to myriad sources of subtly conflicting information in a game where those conflicts matter?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70605/how-can-i-deal-with-pc-access-to-myriad-sources-of-subtly-conflicting-informatio) [closed]
- [Being Descriptive](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47258/being-descriptive) [duplicate]
- [How can I be more descriptive about actions and events in my game?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36861/how-can-i-be-more-descriptive-about-actions-and-events-in-my-game)